Why is AppBar Not Displaying in Flutter App
HereIsAScreenshotOfMyCodeAndSimulator` I am creating a simple Flutter app with an AppBar. I expect the AppBar to be displayed in lime color as specified in the ThemeData, but it does not appear at all. The body text "Hello, Flutter!" is displayed correctly. I have tried restarting VSCode, running flutter clean, and testing on different simulators, but the issue persists.
Here is my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.lime),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Drawer App"),
        elevation: defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android ? 5.0 : 0.0,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Hello, Flutter!"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

What I have tried:
Restarting VSCode
Running flutter clean
Testing on different simulators
Output:
The "Hello, Flutter!" text is displayed, but the AppBar is not visible.`

As per your code and provided image your app bar is display with text Drawer App, if you want to change Appbar color  then add backgroundColor: Colors.blue,

Most probably the problem is with the line of logical elevation provider.Check whether  **defaultTargetPlatform **  is got a value

Override the appBarTheme in ThemeData to have the desired color:
theme: ThemeData(
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lime,
    ),
    useMaterial3: true,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
  ),


This worked like a charm! Thank you so much . It seems like the YouTube videos I've been watching are really outdated.

Can you try with below solution... Hope it will help for you...
 return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('My App'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Text('Hello, World!'),
    ),
  ),
);

